# Reading Firebase Auth to use in

Tags: firebase, nullpointerexception, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a texting app. I have `DashboardActivity` which extends `NavDrawer`. I want to show the profile picture and the user's name on that `NavDrawer`. I have a `ProfileActivity` which successfully shows this data in that activity but whenever I try to put this data in my `NavDrawer`, I get a `NPE` on `mAuth`. I'm trying to set the picture and name in `setContentView()` of my `NavDrawer` class. This is my code:

```
 @Override
    public void setContentView(final int layoutResID) {
        super.setContentView(R.layout.nav_drawer);
         //removed inflating layout code
        final TextView username = findViewById(R.id.txtNavUsername);
        final CircleImageView profilePic = findViewById(R.id.nav_profile_pic);
firestore.collection("Users").document(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    try {
                        String user_image = documentSnapshot.getString("image");
                        username.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("name"));
                        RequestOptions placeholderOption = new RequestOptions();
                        placeholderOption.placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
                        Glide.with(NavDrawer.this).load(user_image).into(profilePic);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

At class level, I have

```
 private FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

What am I doing wrong? Why am I getting the null pointer exception even when the user is logged in?

Comment: At which line of code are you getting `NPE`? Beside that, I have successfully implemeneted in one of my [repos](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseApp-Clean-Architecture-MVVM/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebaseapp/main/MainActivity.java) the same thing, if you have time, you can take a look.

Comment: I was getting it on `mAuth.getCurrenUser().getUid()` that was null. Let me look at your repos. Thanks

Comment: Oh. I got it. I just moved the code to 'drawerOpen()'. Thanks Alex.